# How write Firestore rule to match email field in document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a field labelled 'email' in my 'myCollection' documents and I'm trying to write a firestore rule to permit deletion when the email record of a logged-in user matches the email in the record. I've coded my rule as follows:

```
match /myCollection/{email} {
  allow delete : if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == email;
}
```

This fails to permit the deletion of matching records. Advice would be appreciated because although this question has been asked numerous times on StackOverflow, the answers I've seen are contradictory and none of them works for me.

I'm testing this in "playground" and if I set 'location' to myCollection/{documents = **}, the rule fails. See screenshots below:

[image: Playground (top)]
[image: Playground (bottom)]

The deletion code in my program reads:

```
    const myCollectionCol = collection(db, 'myCollection');
    const myCollectionQuery = query(myCollectionCol, where("email", "==", email));
    const myCollectionSnapshot = await getDocs(myCollectionQuery);
    myCollectionSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        deleteDoc(doc.ref);
    });
```

Comment: "This fails to permit the deletion of matching records." The rule should allow deletion as far as I can see. Can you show how you test this?

Comment: @FVP : Thanks for picking this up Frank. I'm trying two ways, first in my program and second in the "playground". Sticking to the latter, I've set 'Simulation Type' to 'delete' and location to '/myCollection/{document=**}'. Then I've toggle authentication on and set 'email' to a value that exists in 'myCollection". When I click 'run' it bounces me. Remove the && bit of the rule and I'm cleared.

Comment: Instead of adding a description in the comments, can you show a screenshot of the playground in your question (there's an edit link right under it)? Please make sure all relevant fields are visible in there.

Comment: @FVP : I've edited the original question as requested. I've discovered that if I change the playground location to myCollection/samuil.johnson@yahoo.com, where samuil.johnson@yahoo.com is an address in myCollection the rule accepts the deletion. So is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're firing a query that returns all documents that have a field `email` with a value equal to the email variable:

```
query(myCollectionCol, where("email", "==", email))
```

But your rules only allow deleting the document that has its **document ID* equal to the user's email property in their auth token.

So to delete the only document you're allowed to delete:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;
const myEmailAddress = user.email;

...

const myCollectionCol = collection(db, 'myCollection');

deleteDoc(doc(myCollectionCol, myEmailAddress));
```

---

If you want a user to be able to delete all documents where `email` has their email address, that'd be:

```
match /myCollection/{doc} {
  allow delete : if request.auth != null && 
                    request.auth.token.email == resource.data.email;
                                             //  the email field in the doc
}
```

Comment: Wow - this is a subtlety that had gone straight over my head. So, could I ask how I would code a rule to permit a user to delete /all/  documents carrying their email address?