# What variables are available for use as "wildcards" in a Firestore Rules Match Statement?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The syntax for specifying the syntax of a rule that you might want to declare in order to protect documents in a Firestore collection are specified at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage. But this describes the wider context of Google Cloud storage and consequently, when you're trying to use these specifically for Firestore applications, the documentation seems a bit opaque.

The `match` statement used to specify the subset of documents in a collection myCollection to which the rule is to be applied typically takes the form:

```
    match myCollection/{wildcard}
```

My question is "what variables are available for use as wildcards?". According to the Google document referenced above "A wildcard variable is declared in a path by wrapping a variable in curly braces: {variable}. This variable is accessible within the match statement as a string."

I now understand that if `myCollection` contains a field called `email` for example, a match statement of the form

```
    match myCollection/{email}
```

will allow me to specify a rule to be applied to a document whose documentId is the value specified by the email field. In this case, a rule to allow only logged-in users to read their own record in `myCollection` would take the form:

```
    match myCollection/{email}
        allow read : if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == email;
```

where email is the user's email address filed in `myCollection`

But supposing that email isn't being used as the unique key to identify a `myCollection` record - ie that other fields identify documents and a user may have many records tagged with their email within myCollection? This is surely the more likely case but the Google documentation doesn't seem to give any clues to how you would specify a match to cover this situation.

A previous stackoverflow question at [How write Firestore rule to match email field in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69769514/how-write-firestore-rule-to-match-email-field-in-document?noredirect=1#comment123327874_69769514) has directed me towards the keyword `doc`. This has allowed me to specify a more general rule that can be applied to all the records in a collection with a particular email value:

```
    match /myCollection/{doc} {
      allow read : if request.auth != null && 
                      request.auth.token.email == resource.data.email;
}
```

There are two concepts here that are new to me (at least in the context of Firestore rules): first the keyword `doc` and second the `resource.data.email` construct that gives my rule access to document fields. Can anybody tell me where these constructs are documented, and also if there are any more "wrinkles" to the "wildcard" concept (I already know about the documents=** one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match myCollection/{wildcard}` - This rule tells firebase to match all documents in the myCollection collection. Essentially, it says match all documents that match this path `myCollection/*`

`wildcard` above is simply a variable that holds the document path (the asterisks path). This variable can be anything (apart from the reserved strings). If this is your path:

1. 'myCollection/tests', then wildcard variable is holds 'tests';
2. 'myCollection/test@email.com', then wildcard variable holds 'test@email.com'

`wildcard` is simply a place holder for anything that matches this path: `myCollection/*`. Instead of wildcard, you can use anything e.g email (`myCollection/{email}` and email here becomes the variable that holds the document path).

`resource.data` is the data being fetched. So if your data has an 'email' field, then `resource.data.email` always holds the email field data (regardless of what the wildcard variable is). **Do not use reserved strings e.g 'resource' as the wildcard variable.**

> what variables are available for use as wildcards?

Any variable you put in curly braces becomes the wildcard variable. It simply holds the document path. It is not a special string.

**UPDATE @MartinJ.**

For autogenerated ids. Lets assume this is your doc path `myCollection/1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt`, (1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt is autogenerated)

```
match /myCollection/{email} {
  allow read : if email == '1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt'; // true because
  // email variable holds the value '1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt'
}
match /myCollection/{doc} {
  allow read : if doc == '1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt'; // true because
  // doc variable holds the value '1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt'
}
match /myCollection/{stackoverflow} {
  allow read : if stackoverflow == '1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt'; // true 
  // because stackoverflow variable holds the value '1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt'
}
// It does not matter what we use as wildcard variable (we can even 
// use MartinJ), it will always hold the value of '1s6SUqi8M6sC6DZdTKjt' 
// (doc id if the path matches).
// As @Frank said, these are simply variables, not keywords. You 
// can call it anything and it will have the value of doc path.
}
```

if this is your document path `sales/2K5CwGU9ZWwNoO9efyuv/payments/40ciObsicEntBZParkon` (autogenerated document ids)

```
match /sales/{doc=**} {
  allow write: if doc == '2K5CwGU9ZWwNoO9efyuv/payments/40ciObsicEntBZParkon';
  // this will be true because doc=** (**with asterisks**) matches 
  // everything after sales
}
match /sales/{saleId} {
  match /payment/{paymentId} {
    allow write: if saleId == '2K5CwGU9ZWwNoO9efyuv' && paymentId == '40ciObsicEntBZParkon';
    // this will be true because saleId holds the value 
    // '2K5CwGU9ZWwNoO9efyuv' and paymentId holds this value '40ciObsicEntBZParkon'
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer Peter!  These are indeed **variables** and not keywords, so you should treat them just like variable names in code and give them meaningful names based on their context.

Comment: @MartinJ : the wildcard will still hold the value of the auto generated id (if the path matches). Please check out my updated explanation. Also, Frank isn't wrong. You can use {doc}, it doesn't matter (it is not special). And {doc} should work in the playground. Mine works.

Comment: `resource.data` is the actual document your request is trying to fetch. If that data doesn't exist, then `resource.data` will be null and `resource.data.email` will throw Null value error (which you got). This error has nothing to do with the wild card ({doc}). {doc} will hold your document's id. Not the document data.

Comment: @MartinJ, your match statement shouldn't behave differently for `{email}` and `{doc}`. That should not be so. As long as it is its not a reserved string (and you've not used the variable anywhere in your rules) it should behave the same.

Comment: @MartinJ : `resource.data` is from the data to be fetched, while `request.resource.data` is the data from the payload (for update request). Assuming old email is 'test' and you want to update it to 'test2', `resource.data.email == 'test'` while `request.resource.data.email == 'test2'`. NB: For get and delete requests, `request.resource` will be null.

Comment: @Peter O. FInally "clicked"! Many thanks